# How can I get the default browser name in bash script on Mac OS X

Tags: bash, macos, shell, google-chrome, grep

I want to find out if the default browser is Google Chrome on a Mac OS X machine before the script executes.

How can I do it? thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `grep/awk` the launch services preferences list to find out which browser is set as default:

```
x=~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist; \
plutil -convert xml1 $x; \
grep 'https' -b3 $x | awk 'NR==2 {split($2, arr, "[><]"); print arr[3]}'; \
plutil -convert binary1 $x
```

This sets a variable (`x`) to the launch services preferences list, then converts it using `plutil` to `xml` format so we can `grep` it. We locate the string we're looking for (`https`) then output the result. The final step is to convert the plist back to `binary` format.

If chrome is set to be default you will get:

**Result**:

```
com.google.chrome
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to convert, use this script:

```sh
plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist | grep 'https' -b3 |awk 'NR==3 {split($4, arr, "\""); print arr[2]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Getting Default Browser

The following command will print the ID of the default application for `https`:

```sh
defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers \
  | sed -n -e '/LSHandlerURLScheme = https;/{x;p;d;}' -e 's/.*=[^"]"\(.*\)";/\1/g' -e x
```

If Firefox was your default browser, you would get `org.mozilla.firefox`.

##### Explanation

The script reads the corresponding system defaults using the `defaults` command and extracts the ID from the above line of the `https` matching line (more on that can be read up at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206886/print-previous-line-after-a-pattern-match-using-sed).

### Getting Default Application

You could wrap a function around it and allow passing the scheme:

```sh
# Returns the default app for the specified scheme (default: https).
default_app() {
  local scheme=${1:-https}
  defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers \
    | sed -n -e "/LSHandlerURLScheme = $scheme;/{x;p;d;}" -e 's/.*=[^"]"\(.*\)";/\1/g' -e x
}
```

The call would now be

```sh
default_app
# or
default_app https
```

#### Interacting with Default Browser/Application

I guess you would like to do something with the ID as well.
Integrating with Apple Script can be achieved with `application id`.

The following shell script runs an Apple Script that activates / focusses / brings to front your default browser:

```sh
osascript <<APPLE_SCRIPT
tell application id "$(default_app)"
  activate
end tell
APPLE_SCRIPT
```

Same as a one-liner:

```sh
osascript -e "tell application id \"$(default_app)\"" -e 'activate' -e 'end tell'
```

Comment: Not sure why no upvotes yet, but you got mine! Thanks for the thorough and detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

The current accepted answer converts one of the preference files to XML and then back to binary, if something fails in the middle, your file might get corrupt.

The best way to convert the file without modifying it when using `plutil` is setting the output to the STDIN with the `-o -` option.

If you have `jq` installed, a more accurate way to obtain the bundle ID for the default browser would be as follows:

```bash
plutil \
    -convert json -o - \
    "$HOME"'/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist' \
    | jq -r '.LSHandlers[] | select( .LSHandlerURLScheme=="https" ) | .LSHandlerRoleAll'
```

If what you want is the application path under `/Applications`, you can execute the following:

```bash
mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = "$(
    plutil \
        -convert json -o - \
        "$HOME"'/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist' \
        | jq -r '.LSHandlers[] | select( .LSHandlerURLScheme=="https" ) | .LSHandlerRoleAll'
)" \
    | grep -E '^/Applications/'
```